# Show that number $2^{3n}+3^{4n}$ is not divisible by number 73

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, divisibility

I used mathematical induction.

1. For a basis, let $n=1$:

   $2^{3}+3^{4}=89$

   which is clearly not divisible by $73$.
2. Let's suppose that $2^{3n}+3^{4n} = 8^{n} + 81^{n}$  is **not** divisible by $73$.
3. Then for $n+1$ we have:

   $2^{3(n+1)}+3^{4(n+1)} = 8^{n+1} + 81^{n+1} = 8^{n}.8 + 81^{n}*81$

Because we supposed $8^{n} + 81^{n}$ is not divisible by 73 and numbers $8$ and $81$ are clearly not divisible by 73, number $2^{3n}+3^{4n}$ is not divisible by $73$. Is this correct or should I take different approach?

Comment: $2^{3n}+3^{4n} \bmod 73$ is periodic of period 3: $55,2,16,55,2,16,\dots$

Comment: @lhf That basically comes from $8$ having order $3$ modulo $73$.

Answer (score 3):

That resoning is incorrect. For example $a,b=2,3$ and $a+b$ are not divisible by 6, but $3a+2b$ is. Rather take this approach: You have already reasoned that $2^{3n}+3^{4n} = 8^n+81^n$.

Now let’s take this modulo $73$. As $81=73+8\equiv 8\mod 73$ we have
$$ 2^{3n}+3^{4n} \equiv 2\cdot 8^n\mod 73$$
Now as $73$ is prime we trivially have $2,8$ are units modulo $73$. Thus this cannot be $0$.

Comment: I'm apparently even lazier than someone with the username Lazy. I don't want to check that $73$ is prime; however, it's enough to know that $73$ is not a power of $2$ (because, in particular, it's odd). Therefore $2 \cdot 8^n = 2^{3n+1}$ can never be divisible by $73$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Come on, you do not need to check that $73$ is prime. It is quite obvious that neither of $2,3,5,7$ can divide $73$.

Comment: I understand that $2⋅8^{n}  mod  73$ can never be 0 and its periodic of period: $55, 2, 16, 55, 2, ...$ but I don't quite understand how we we got it.

Comment: @wizard844 $81$ has rest $8$ modulo $73$. So $8^n + 81^n$ has the same rest as $8^n+8^n$.